# Associating Uniqueconstraint as foreign key in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is my scenario, i am trying to associate entity B to entity A via OneToMany relationship using `@JoinColumn` with the columnns a1, a2, a3 and i got the error `referenced column names not mapped to a single property`. Later i tried `@Uniqueconstraint` with a1, a2, and a3 columns on table A and i am not able to succeed on this. Could any of you help me in associating entity B to A as @OnToMany relationship?

```
A
--
a1
a2
a3

PrimaryKey -- a1 and a2

B
--
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2

PrimaryKey -- a1, a2, a3, and b1

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
Class A
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private APK apk;

    @Column(name="a3")
    private Integer a3;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
    private Set<B> bSet;
}

@Embeddable
Class APK
{
    @Column(name="a1")
    private Integer a1;

    @Column(name="a2")
    private Integer a2;     
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
Class B
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private BPK bpk;

    @Column(name="b2")
    private Integer b2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="a1", referencedColumnName="a1", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="a2", referencedColumnName="a2", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="a3", referencedColumnName="a3", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private A a;
}

@Embeddable
Class BPK
{
    @Column(name="a1")
    private Integer a1;

    @Column(name="a2")
    private Integer a2; 

    @Column(name="a3")
    private Integer a2;     

    @Column(name="b1")
    private Integer b1; 
}
```

Comment: If a1 and a2 are used to uniquely identify A, why are you using a1,a2 and a3 in B?  Did you mean to set all 3 as the primary key?  What mappings did you try?

Comment: Chris, a1, a2 in A table along will make as primary key. One A entity can have many B entities and B is uniquely identified using a3 along with Primary key of A. So i need a3 in B table.

Comment: If (a1,a2) are unique, then a3 does not help uniquely identify an A;   B will point to a single A using (a1,a2).  You are just duplicating a value field in B that already exists in A.  JPA only allows using the full, unique primary key for references anyway.  You can use a foreign key that references something other then the target's pk, but it won't be portable to all JPA providers, and won't allow efficient cache hits when traversing relationships.

Answer (score 0):

a3 isn't part of A's primary key and so shouldn't be needed in the B table.

There are a few ways to map this, but if using JPA 2.1 I would use:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
Class A
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private APK apk;

    @Column(name="a3")
    private Integer a3;

    @OneToMany(mappedby='a')
    List bList;
}

@Embeddable
Class APK
{
    @Column(name="a1")
    private Integer a1;

    @Column(name="a2")
    private Integer a2;     
}


@Entity
@IdClass(BPK.class)
@Table(name = "B")
Class B
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="b1")
    private Integer b1; 

    @Column(name="b2")
    private Integer b2;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="a1", referencedColumnName="a1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="a2", referencedColumnName="a2")
    })
    private A a;
}

@Embeddable
Class BPK
{
    private APK a;     
    private Integer b1; 
}
```

There are many many ways to map it though.

Comment: Chris, updated my post with the mappings i tried. In your code, i see b1 in B table has been referenced in BPK and also in B class as `@Id`? In my scenario, B table can have the uniqueness by including a3. One A entity can have many B.

Comment: b1 is referenced only once, using the Id annotation.  The attribute is used within the BPK though, which I marked as a IdClass instead of using it as an embeddable.  If you want to continue to use the key class as an embeddedId, go ahead - you just need to remove the b2 ID mapping and mark the 'a' mapping with MapsId instead of Id.  As for using 'a3' in your mappings - I don't understand.  The model I have shown gives you a OneToMany relationship from A->B and ManyToOne from B->A without using a3.  a3 would only be relevant if you were using a partial key instead of a unique key